# New "Responsive Design mode" in Safari: Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox Emulator

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

In the new version of Safari there is a new "Responsive Design Mode". You can switch between Safari, Internet Explorer (7,8,9,10) and Firefox. Is it actually running Windows Internet Explorer 7 if I click it?

On a page with icons it changed the positioning of the icon when I changed to IE 7.

It would be pretty helpful if they would actually emulate IE...

---

**Edit:**

The same website, on the left with safari selected and on the right site with IE 7.

*Image*:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxm8k.jpg

*Image 2:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/8onNf.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this WWDC 2015 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-505/?time=1764), it is stated that setting the user agent in the responsive design mode *sets the UA string only*; nothing more. No emulation or whatsoever. Besides, making IE work on OS X would require both tremendous effort and collaboration of Microsoft and Apple. I don't think it will ever happen, especially not for an extension for a non-profit software.

I know this answer doesn't explain your screenshots but I can not comment more on that without seeing the code, yet my 2 cents would be on the css prefixes. Safari might be ignoring / applying them according to the user-agent and that would explain the difference. IE conditional tags would be another possibility that comes to mind.